# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a error for unity3d,
this is the part of code:

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab) && OpenInventory() = true)
    {
        CloseInventory();
    }
```

and I followed some questions on stack overflow and unityanswers, and I tried this,

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab) && OpenInventory() == true)
    {
        CloseInventory();
    }
```

now it got the error:
cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'bool'
can someone help me?thanks!

Comment: What is `OpenInventory`? Please provide its code.

Answer (score 1):

If `OpenInventory()` returns void (e.g. `void OpenInventory() { ...}`) then you cannot compare it to a Boolean value. Make sure `OpenInventory()` returns a `bool` and your code will work.

Comment: void OpenInventory()
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
this is what the openinveotry() is

Comment: What is the purpose of OpenInventory? It seems like you're trying to check if the inventory is open before closing it, but your OpenInventory method does not represent the state of the inventory. I'd recommend creating a new property that represents whether the inventory is open, then you can replace your `OpenInventory() == true` check with `IsInventoryOpen` and an implicit true check. Then, in each of your OpenInventory() and CloseInventory() methods, set `IsInventoryOpen` to the correct state value.

Comment: i am sorry i am new to programming idk what you mean, can you maybe give me an example? thanks!

Comment: `void` means your method `OpenInventory()` returns nothing, but you're trying to compare it to a Boolean value of `true`. With regards to properties, I'd recommend you do some more reading/watching on the C# language and follow along with some tutorials to get started. [Here is a guide to properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).